# In Fiddler how can I see the list of filters added by "Filter Now"?

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler you can:

1. Right click on a session
2. Select **Filter Now**
3. Show/hide domain/process

[image: Filter Now]

These filters do not show up in the Filters tab. Mine is empty:

[image: Filters tab]

How do you see the list of filters you've added? How a filter you've added?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Once you've added filters, they show up below the list of sessions:

[image]

Each filter looks like a link. It is underlined when you mouse over it. But clicking on it does nothing which is a bit confusing.

Right clicking on a filter removes it. This means that future traffic will not be filtered. However, removing a filter does not restore "hidden" sessions to the list. Filtered sessions seem to be removed.

The number in parenthesis, **Filters (8)**, is the count of how many sessions have been hidden.

Closing and restarting Fiddler also clears that list of filters.

Comment: Is there a way to manually add these?  Adding /js/; /includes/;  in the "Hide if URL Contains" filtering field didn't quite do the same thing as how you add the above entries.  Since they clear at restart, I'd rather use the Filters information which sticks around.

Comment: it would; be spectacular if Fiddler would persist these.

Comment: Because using *Filter Now* is not persisted and only **blacklists** (cannot **whitelist**), I find the *Filters* tab more useful for all but the most ad-hoc filtering.

Comment: is there a way in Fiddler to filter by some parameters, remove those parameters and in the effect restore filtered sessions and then apply new filtering? I'm looking for a quick way to apply few different filters on the same set of HTTP requests

Comment: the list is stored in `My Documents\Fiddler2\FilterNowRules.xml`

Comment: Closing and restarting Fiddler doesn't clear the list. Maybe it used to do this in an earlier version. As Slai mentioned, the filters are stored in FilterNowRules.xml and it seems Fiddler loads the file when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

awilkinson's answer is correct, but I've found the best place to view the full list of filters is in the

> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Fiddler2\FilterNowRules.xml

file since I normally have a ton of filters and finding them in that tiny area on-screen is difficult.

The area below the Sessions block on-screen is good if you only have a couple, but once that list grows it's cumbersome and a pain to find one you're looking for.

Here's an example of the XML format, you can see that things are well organized.  If opened in an editor you can quickly search for and find what you need to remove or add one.  Note that you'll need to close Fiddler and re-open for any changes to be picked up since the file is not watched:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FilterNowRules xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ShowOnlyPID>-1</ShowOnlyPID>
  <BlockedPIDs />
  <BlockedProcessNames>
    <string>outlook:</string>
    <string>perfwatson2:</string>
    <string>fiddler:</string>
  </BlockedProcessNames>
  <BlockedHostNames>
    ...
    <string>www.youtube.com</string>
    <string>yt3.ggpht.com</string>
    <string>youtube.com</string>
    <string>fonts.googleapis.com</string>
    <string>static.doubleclick.net</string>
    <string>ad.doubleclick.net</string>
  </BlockedHostNames>
  <BlockedPaths>
    <string>/telemetry.request</string>
  </BlockedPaths>
  <BlockedMIMEs />
  <BlockedURLsContaining>
    <string>.google.com</string>
    <string>.office.com</string>
    ...
  </BlockedURLsContaining>
</FilterNowRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me not showing any sessions also no filter enabled and selected any process but when checked Help - Troubleshot enabled showing correctly . finally open file :
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Fiddler2\FilterNowRules.xml
and delete unused rule .after close and open fiddler all thing is fine and showing sessions correctly fine